# Segment trees max queries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, intervals, processing-efficiency

I have a typical segment tree that stores max range elements. And on the otherhand i have a dymanic list of intervals,

whats the most effeicent way to query those intervals for max elements?

For e.g

```
 List1 =[(1,6),(9,13),(16,20)]
 List2 = [(1,4),(13,15),(21,25)]
```

Now the query will be like, for e.g List1, get the kth largest element from the segment. Is there a way not to iterate through all those intervals once the segment tree gets updated ?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic list of intervals... like is the input coming in all the time, or it's like one time a list of elements arrive and then you process over it, because only in the later case segment trees are efficient data structures. Can you post an example, it makes things a lot clear

Comment: You can think of it as users have intervals of numbers, and those intervals represents item ranges that the user can see, for example a user clicked on an item the list of ranges he can see after is dynamically changed (e.g. one range will split up into two ranges). Now the user will query will be something similar to largest item or kth largest item but this item index must be included in one of those ranges he has. I hope things are more clear now. Thank you

Comment: No things are not clear yet, so segment trees are not used to find kth largest element but they are used to query a range of elements like if we have a list {1,2,3,5,6} so 3 is the largest element in the range {0,2}. Can you please provide a nice example in the post. I will then be able to solve it

Comment: Done Added an example. But notice that i need a way to not iterate through lists every time Thanks

Comment: Ohk got it, let me work on an algorithm for this scenario. I think I know how to solve this.

Comment: But you won't be able to find kth largest element unless the tree is in the form of a binary tree with left and right child. So I will put up an explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: If you do it, it will be amazing, this problem actually exhausted me. And it wont matter what type of trees i will need use, as long as complexity is kept minimum. Many thanks :)

Comment: One question i want to ask the inervals are alwasy in increasing order ?

Comment: Yes, and they will never be overlapping for the same user.